# Can't parse Map<String, Double> with Moshi in Kotlin - Unexpected primitive double

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

```
val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
val type = Types.newParameterizedType(Map::class.java, String::class.java, Double::class.java)
val adapter = moshi.adapter<Map<String, Double>>(type)

val result = adapter.fromJson(InitData.json)
```

just switching from Gson to Moshi and i ran into this problem. I expect above code to work since it seems to work fine with `Map<String, String>`.

I'm getting an **IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected primitive double. Use the boxed type**

Same thing for Float. I know what's happening here but is this not possible with Moshi?

This is using `com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.8.0`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `Types.newParameterizedType(Map::class.java, String::class.java, Double::class.javaObjectType)`

[javaOjectType](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java-object-type.html) returns the corresponding boxed type for primitive types.

Comment: cool that works, was using `Any` and map to `Double` in the meantime, thanks! Didn't know about `javaObjectType`